# Wait for half of the promises to resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to parallel process a number of asynchronous calls in `NodeJS`. I can continue if a specific number of those calls resolve or all of them are completed(some resolve, some reject). How to to do this?

[`Promise.All()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) resolves when all of the promises are completed and [`Promise.Any()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) resolves when any one of the promise is resolved or all are rejected. Is there any way to wait for 50% of the promises to resolve or `n` number of promises to resolve instead of waiting for all to resolve.

Comment: If all of them are settled but not enough did fulfill, what do you want the result to be? Do you need the fulfillment values and rejection reasons, similar to how `allSettled` returns them? Do you care about the order of results?

Comment: I don't care about the order. If I get n fulfillments, I would not care about the failures. Also at the time of asking this questions I was considering that all of my promises would eventually resolve. one way or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a function that attaches a then callback to each given `Promise`, incrementing the count each time (or pushing the results to an array) and resolving once the count reaches a certain value.

A basic example:

```js
function nResolve(promises, n) {
  if (n < 0) throw Error('Invalid n: ' + n);
  let results = [], rejected = 0;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!n) resolve([]);
    else promises.forEach(promise => promise.then(res => {
      results.push(res); // note: order is unpredictable
      if (results.length === n) resolve([...results]);
    }, err => {
      // reject only when there are not enough promises left for n to resolve
      if (++rejected > promises.length - n) reject();
    }));
  });
}
const delay = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(ms);
  r(ms);
}, ms));
nResolve([delay(2000), delay(100), delay(500), delay(1000), delay(2000), 
  delay(3000), delay(5000), delay(10000)], 4)
  .then(results => console.log('4 Promises resolved', results));
```

Comment: I think this should work. `nResolve` should also collect the resolved outputs and pass that as its own resolution output.

Comment: @SanjaySB The code can be altered to store the results of the promises as well, but the order will not be deterministic. Is that what you want?

Comment: This does handle neither `n=0` nor rejections properly.

Comment: @Bergi Good point; I've updated the example. But it's not really clear from the question exactly what the appropriate way to handle them is.

Answer (score 4):

**first attempt**

It's hard to imagine a use case for your function but it's an interesting problem to solve. `firstN` accepts an `Array<Promise<T>>` and a number, `n`. It resolves a `Map<number, T>` where the number corresponds to the promise's index in the input array. You can verify on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAnAzlAcgHgCoB8AFAA6pwC2M6ApugFyICCqqAhgJ44AK5Vt+AgQA0iMIzAgKAIxqoAlI16VqNHAFk2JHJJlzRhAogDeAKESIYwRESRGyK2ugB0AGxpgA5lAAW8xKg0UCCoSMr8NM6BAFY00EQAoqxwqEQAREjUiFBwcIiegWxQafLy5ojuUAF0cK4AbnSIALyIAAzllchsMK4hjS3tFqCQsAgVuSREFFqMmtq6sqii4ao4hQAmCK4ciADaC-qIeAC6QoqIKwJzOlKLBkIm5RaBwaEXfKpPFohRbBA0RBY7A4zmAfCmWmcdTYvToRFKZW+32cvg8RC+SKIuxg61EdWO-iaRjMSNJlmsRAA1JTAuhag10M0mi0wP4XiEkGAaAB3RBzeHOWhQIg4vGIsnfaYkZzrGiVAE48US6qvJCuCYQkjyFE+NG0qpE6qYQVBEW4xB1UoY74AX2E1osWNFiBoBOaxId3ysNmpwG6vVpiHsHycbg83h8iAAtGJ-L5yLykuRUmkcnlpmAdn6en10CVPRYpTK5UEFeslRL2W91XBJlKK0ibdbxU3nkEOWImW0vgB+d6OSK0+kArm8-lWpGMGuTUd8rSkEN0ZxSoikUSK92e7Hm6WosBEOruvbO-GINiMiAITDaiBFCA+Ig0I+XQc0WLxbeiV1ni9XqClY4f0QS8wEwZsrSbUwQMwRBZVcThmhsEhzwYRBpFydw2FZI8pgYA4FE3CxZxfG49FQYgiFpUQYkJIwhTwGAKBoOAQGFZD0EZPtA0YGJRAodA+PQK0oL-RB2MZFo4M4IgoFQEAaDKaCqmzVxEKkjgiD9VxaDKETQKqKA6CgABGRDdnEogAA5WnkUQLOMmzRBUogAGZHLElCiAATnciyAFZ3OcgAmXzPIANlCjiiAAFkC-0iAAdki9AiAcmzjlMPS6XcFFGIBVMjOM-MUAwbAZMK0QXPFHU0Wg2pInVTxRDqnK5GTaqUDAGFtlXWjgKvercqYhIwHWdJDMwIrhKU7IjKCsyLOs2yuh6VK4tWtzlucnytvigLdtWkKDtcIgIuOmL1pOpLlvs1p0sylrIlgJjxrm4q0EwLByswILKuqvciEetw4Ca-rQMGtqUg6mAutcHr4SPIHnpoEaxoKn6Sl0maJqgFyFs8pa7M8naiaizaMqywbkdezAXPe0qvpxlzRBs8oav3IHGuagbWuSBQ2c67qNIRw0kby1GadxzGHtEnHovxqLCY8qKdopsWXvRqBovpz7vq1v62YBzmQe58HefagWYaF3rEZ5p7xdGyXtdKIA) -

```
function firstN<T>(promises: Array<Promise<T>>, n: number): Promise<Map<number, T>> {
  let resolves = 0
  let failures = 0
  function loop(map: Map<number, Promise<readonly [number, T]>>): Promise<Map<number, T>> {
    return Promise
      .race(Array.from(map.values()))
      .then(
        ([id, v]) => {
          if (++resolves === n) return new Map().set(id, v)
          map.delete(id)
          return loop(map).then(rest => rest.set(id, v))
        },
        ([id, e]) => {
          if (++failures > promises.length - n) throw Error("too many failures")
          map.delete(id)
          return loop(map)
        }
      )
  }
  return n == 0
    ? Promise.resolve(new Map())
    : loop(new Map(promises.map((p, id) =>
        [id, p.then(v => [id, v] as const).catch(e => Promise.reject([id, e] as const))] as const
      )))
}
```

To test it, we'll mock a `pass` and `fail` functions that resolve after `ms` milliseconds -

```
const delay = (pass: boolean) => (ms:number) =>
  new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(pass ? res : rej, ms, ms))

const pass = delay(true)
const fail = delay(false)
```

Now create some promises and resolve the first 3 -

```
const test1 = [
  pass(80), pass(10), fail(30), pass(90), pass(50),
  fail(20), pass(60), pass(40), fail(70), pass(100)
]

console.time("test1")
firstN(test1, 3)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
  .finally(() => console.timeEnd("test1"))
```

The first ones to resolve are the shortest, 10, 40, and 50. Keys 1, 7, and 4 correspond to their position in the input. Most importantly, note the total running time is equal to the longest promise of the bunch -

```
Map (3) {4 => 50, 7 => 40, 1 => 10} 
first 3: 53.608 ms
```

In a second test, we'll ensure proper failure when insufficient promises resolve. In this test, 8 out of 10 promises fail, making it impossible to fulfill `n=3` -

```
const test2 = [
  pass(80), fail(10), fail(30), fail(90), fail(50),
  fail(20), fail(60), fail(40), fail(70), pass(100)
]

console.time("test2")
firstN(test2, 3)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
  .finally(() => console.timeEnd("test2"))
```

Only 80 and 100 pass. Once 90 fails, our function has enough information to know that success is impossible and an early rejection is provided -

```
[ERR]: too many failures 
test2: 92.656ms
```

In our third test, we verify the immediate exit of `n=0` and proper return of an empty Map -

```
const test3 = [pass(80), pass(90), pass(30)]

console.time("test3")
firstN(test3, 0)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
  .finally(() => console.timeEnd("test3"))
```

```
Map (0) {} 
test3: 1.413ms
```

Finally we test the scenario where `n` exceeds the number of supplied promises. We see an immediate rejection with appropriate message -

```
console.time("test4")
firstN(test4, 3)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
  .finally(() => console.timeEnd("test4"))
```

```
[ERR]: n is too great
test4: 1.728ms
```

**second attempt**

Initially I was thinking in terms of Set and Map as means of taking advantage of `Promise.race` in a loop. I did a refactor after completing the first draft of the program and [passes the tests](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAnAzlAcgHgCoB8AFAA6pwC2M6ApugFyICCqqAhgJ44AK5Vt+AgQA0iMIzAgKAIxqoAlI16VqNHAFk2JHJJlzRhAogDeAKESIICTIlR0QAGyiIAvGJoB3RJu27ZqA2J5c0QHGmdgNhgHEDt0V0QABhCYYEQiJBc3RPlbcNikZX4aADo4uAcANxoMz28tInlgi1T0pCMyFVp0ErCwAHMoAAtcuygCxCLVMpoAKxpoIgBRVjhUIgAiJGpEKDg4RH67NigNppCxibA6qdoiInKqmlE7eehclyMzCwtgNfSrGAbABtGAAE1EJAAuog4GlOsUejQwFBUDA6I1ct8fhYSCVhsiiCEcRZKq4vsSSS00g97E4SugYAAvGiIHBiUZ0qAM8JEcGiSrNKk-Vq09CObmMlmuNxgTnoCrVMUSoVUgC+wkpONZnxMWpJooA1IbItFYnREB0+Koen1BkNEABaDn6qmvBZQZardYbPYHChsMAcZBRGJxM6qklq-WR6MWNXBaOmQE2ME0BycBKkNjoBiIaT7MKBj5GIgUBh+OQlkLXLy3NSV1DEMUvOYlxC0KB4GAUGhwECekg5+IAfjy8UYr1E5en6HOyesziHuYSaYzHCIqJANGCKYiodX6c4REiDlowQXQOcUDoUAAjAlgcv0EQABw5SHDoh3j8h6JEABmX9nyIABOYCvwAVl-U0HCIAAmCDcyIAA2JCXwAFhg0MiAAdnQ79EhyKFTEvBUwnxHsal9W87zOUwUAwbBN1o0QAKFfEhkJFMKlKBw4H6UQeIouRyAUEIShQMA2AcBwN0aclLGsXjKN7JYwDBTYb0wOj5z3XZb3gx8QPfeRRFgwizL-OCgKsizwLsnDoMc-9EJcuC0PcogsK8-CrJAn9iNI4TSlgXstMM+jGMwLAWMweC2I4gkwCIELegEoTlJE70OKkmS5Puds0rCmh1M0mj4ojYLFwMzAAOMr9TM-ZCHOal9bJIsiVJKiK6qitAYriqAANEHIJOS1Ksr4jKlKBFTRLWXKYGk2T5KKqbVNKjTeuGqqyOvW8MIa5CmsQECHM64qqJ2jD+qY2LtKgDDEvGriUrS-jBNm8jSgW8SLEk5b8rWxSrrU7aKqeiMgA) above with a reduction in implementation complexity -

```
function firstN<T>(promises: Array<Promise<T>>, n: number): Promise<Map<number, T>> {
  const result = new Map<number, T>()
  let failures = 0
  if (n == 0) return Promise.resolve(new Map())
  if (n > promises.length) return Promise.reject(Error("n is too great"))
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (const [id, p] of promises.entries()) {
      p.then(
        v => {
          if (result.size < n) result.set(id, v)
          if (result.size == n) resolve(result)
        },
        e => {
          if (++failures > promises.length - n)
            reject(Error("too many failures"))
        }
      )
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I suggest breaking your habit of writing mocks that use `random`.  If you write a mock that uses `random` it's not unit testable because you don't know the expected output.

Comment: @Wyck i always provide a demo where possible, but most answers on SO don't come with a unit testing suite. i updated my post with your suggestion :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one:

```js
function mkProm(name){
 return new Promise((res,rej)=> // 50% of all promises are expected to be rejected
  setTimeout(()=>Math.random()>.5?res(name):rej(name+" rejected!"), Math.random()*2000+200) );
}
function firstn(parr,n){
 return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
  let rp={},m=parr.length-n+1,rmsg="*** firstn rejected. ***";
  if(n<1) res(rp); // nothing to do ...
  if(m<1) rej(rmsg); // impossible to achieve ...
  parr.forEach((p,i)=>p.then(r=>{
   console.log(r); // for demo and debugging purposes only ...
   rp[i]=r;
   if(!--n) res(rp);
  }, err=>{
   console.log(m-1,err); // for demo only ...
   if(!--m) rej(rmsg)
  }) )
 })
}

firstn([mkProm("one"),mkProm("four"),mkProm("two"),mkProm("three"),mkProm("seven"),mkProm("five"),mkProm("six")],3)
.then(console.log,console.log)
```

The `firstn` promise behaves a little bit like `Promise.all()`. It will be resolved once the first `n` promises have been resolved and will supply an object:

- its keys are the indices of the fulfilled promises
- its values are their individually resolved data.

The expression `!--n` decrements the (local) counter `n` and returns `false` for all non-zero values.

**Update**:
Following @Bergi's comment I have now also included a proper reject treatment. If too many resolves are demanded in the first place (`n>parr.length`) then the `firstn` promise will reject right away. Otherwise `m=parr.length-n+1` will be decremented after each individual promise rejection and as soon `m==0` the main (`firstn`) promise will also be rejected.

@Wyck suggested using a deterministic function instead of `Math.random()` to make unit testing possible. OK, here is a version with a simple pseudo-random number generator:

```js
function mkPR(m,seed=Math.PI){ // generate a pseudo-random generator function
 return function(){
  seed=(1+seed*seed)%100;
  return Math.floor(seed%1*m);
 }
}   
const rnd2000=mkPR(2000);

function mkProm(name,rnd){
 return new Promise((res,rej)=> // 50% of all promises are expected to be rejected
  setTimeout(()=>rnd()?res(name):rej(name+" rejected!"), rnd2000()+200) );
}
function firstN(parr,n){
 return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
  let rp={},m=parr.length-n+1,rmsg="*** firstN rejected. ***";
  if(n<1) res(rp); // nothing to do ...
  if(m<1) rej(rmsg); // impossible to achieve ...
  parr.forEach((p,i)=>p.then(r=>{
   console.log(r); // for demo and debugging purposes only ...
   rp[i]=r;
   if(!--n) res(rp);
  }, err=>{
   console.log(m-1,err); // for demo only ...
   if(!--m) rej(rmsg)
  }) )
 })
}

const test="one,two,three,four,five,six,seven".split(",");

function prnt(k){return function(...args){console.log(args);console.log(`--- firstN promise ${k} settled ----\n`);}}

(async ()=>{
 let rnd=mkPR(2,2.50);
 for (let k=1;k<=2;k++)
  await firstN(test.map(t=>mkProm(`${k}-${t}`,rnd)),3)
  .then(prnt(k),prnt(k))
})()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100% !important}
```

**Observation:**
I prefixed the promises names of the two runs with `"1-"` and `"2-"`. As the second run already starts as soon as the first `firstN`-promise is resolved, the rest the individual promises of that first run will continue to be resolved/rejected during the second run.

Comment: This does handle neither `n=0` nor rejections properly.

Comment: what happens when some promises fail and `n` promises cannot be resolved? `firstn` will be stuck pending forever.

Comment: Reject treatment added. Please check again.

Answer (score -3):

[`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)  accept an array of async calls . You cant first add 50% of your calls and then other 50%.

it'll return an array with the result and status [rejected or resolved]

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 100, 'foo'));
const promises = [promise1, promise2];

Promise.allSettled(promises).
  then((results) => results.forEach((result) => console.log(result.status)));

// Expected output:
// "fulfilled"
// "rejected"
```

Comment: But I dont know which 50% will resolve first.. right?

Comment: you clod use a variable like firstHalf  to store the returned array without using then block .can you explain why you need to know which badge it is. I could help with clean code